prove the formula for variance when assuming Infinite Probability Spaces
In mcs.pdf, it says Theorem 19.5.1:

Theorem 19.5.1. For any random variables $R_1$ and $R_2$ ,
$$
\text{Ex}[R_1 + R_2]=\text{Ex}[R_1]+\text{Ex}[R_2].
$$
Proof. Let $T ::= R_1 + R_2$ . The proof follows straightforwardly by rearranging
terms in equation (19.2) in the definition of expectation:
$$
\begin{align}
  \text{Ex}[T]&::=\sum_{w\in S}T(w)\cdot\Pr[w]\\
              &=\sum_{w\in S}(R_1(w) + R_2(w))\cdot\Pr[w]\tag{def of T}\\
              &=\sum_{w\in S}R_1(w)\cdot\Pr[w]+ \sum_{w\in S}R_2(w)\cdot\Pr[w]\tag{rearranging terms}\\
              &=\text{Ex}[R_1]+\text{Ex}[R_2]\tag{by (19.2)}
\end{align}
$$


Definition 19.4.1. If R is a nonnegative real-valued random variable defined on a
sample space S, then the expectation of R is
$$
\text{Ex}[R] ::=\sum_{w\in S}T(w)\cdot\Pr[w]\tag{19.2}
$$

The book doesn't inhibit Infinite Probability Spaces which is said in 17.5.4. And it says in the context of Theorem 19.4.4:

Theorem 19.4.4. A countable sum of nonnegative real numbers converges to the
same value, or else always diverges, regardless of the order in which the numbers
are summed.
In fact as long as reordering terms in the infinite sum (19.2) for expectation
preserves convergence, we can allow random variables R taking negative as well
as positive values.

It says we need to care about the order of summation when doing Infinite Sums $\text{Ex}[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}R_i]$ in 19.5.5 Infinite Sums.
But IMHO we also need to care about that order when manipulating with Infinite Probability Spaces. For example if $R_1(w)=w,R_2(w)=-w,S=\mathbb{N}$, then $\text{Ex}[R_1]$ and $\text{Ex}[R_2]$ doesn't exist but $\text{Ex}[R_1+R_2]=0$. So it is one counterexample of Theorem 19.5.1 if not assuming $R_{1,2}$ are nonnegative.
But Theorem 19.5.1 uses (19.2) which implies it assumes $R_{1,2}$ are nonnegative although it says "any random variables".

Then in Lemma 20.3.1, it derives variance same as wikipedia:
$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\operatorname {Var} (X)&=\operatorname {E} \left[(X-\operatorname {E} [X])^{2}\right]\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}-2X\operatorname {E} [X]+\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\right]\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-2\operatorname {E} [X]\operatorname {E} [X]+\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-2\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}+\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\\[4pt]&=\operatorname {E} \left[X^{2}\right]-\operatorname {E} [X]^{2}\end{aligned}}}
$$
The book says the 3rd equality uses "linearity of expectation", but as Theorem 19.5.1 and Definition 19.4.1 says, we need $X^2$ and $-X\operatorname {E}[X]$ both to be nonnegative which is  impossible. Then how to prove the formula for variance assuming Infinite Probability Spaces?

This is all covered in standard probability theory texts like PTE by Durrett. The main results are if 1. $X, Y \geq 0$, then $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. 2. If $E(|X|) < \infty$ and $E(|Y|) < \infty$, then $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. When you deal with variances, there is an implicit assumption of square integrability, so the second theorem applies.

@Mason Thanks. Then the book and wikipedia may assume $E(|X|)<\infty$, etc. When I learnt probability in the undergraduate course, I paid little attention to infinity cases. Maybe my teacher said briefly about infinity at that time but I missed.
